# Analyzer warning: "Incorrect decrement of the reference count" for UITabBarController

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

**Description:**

Let's say I've got a class that contains `UITabBarController` and a bunch of controllers.

Now, one of the controllers (**specialController**) is not allowed to be selected by `UITabBarController`. I show him in different way (but I still want to have him in `UITabBarController`'s `viewControllers`)

By disallowing **specialController** to be selected, I'm missing `init` done by `UITabBarController`. That's why I call `init` on it by hand.

**The problem:**

When I run "Build and Analyzie", I receive warning

> Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is
>       not owned at this point by the caller

in the line with my`init`. But, the application works. What am I missing?

**Code:**

in the ClassA.m

```
//called in viewDidLoad
- (void)makeVoodooOnViewControllers {
    //set all variables etc.
    for (int i = 0; i<controllersCount; i++) {
      UIViewController *tabViewController = [tabBarController.viewControllers
                                                             objectAtIndex:i];
     //CUT - some irrelevant code

     if ([tabViewController isKindOfClass:[specialController class]]) {
       //line below throws a warning
       specialControllerProperty = [((specialController *)tabViewController) init];
     }
}
```

If I'm not clear, please let me know :). Thanks!

Comment: You use `retain` to increase the reference count, not `init`

Comment: Huh? I don't want to increase reference count, I want to `init` the controller. Please, check my description :)

Answer (score 0):

How do the view controllers get into the tabBarController.viewControllers array?

If they are setup in the xib file then init is called as part of reanimating them from the xib and should not be called again.  It's almost never the case that you want to call init anywhere except directly after you call alloc.  Having an alloc'd but unitialized object hanging around seems like a very (very!) rare and unlikely to be desirable situation....

Fundamentally, having a controller in the tab controller controllers list that isn't part of the tab controller controlled controllers seems like a bad design idea - counter the the expectations and design of the tab controller class... and thus likely to cause problems.

Comment: Answering the question - yes, the controllers are added in the xib file.

As for the second paragraph:
I kinda disagree - as far as I understand UITabBarController, that's what it's doing - it does **not** init the controllers untill you show them for the first time. That is the reason I use it - to have the fancy memory management out of my plate. The **specialController** is different, as per description.

Comment: I believe that objects in an xib file are inited then flattened with NSCoder so the init is effectively been called.  That's why there is the awakeWithNib: method - it's the place to do run-time initialization of classes that are being reanimated from an xib file.  That said, I haven't dug into UITabControllers in detail.  Just used them in cases where they just worked without any weirdness.

Comment: If you create custom controller, override it's init method to just print something to log, then add it to UITabBarController BUT never select it - you won't see the init message in the log.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying - that's because it's constructed in IB and then flattened to the xib file.  awakeWithNib: is called upon unflattening in your client code.  You should not be calling init again.

Comment: Btw do you mean `awakeFromNib`?

I've added NSLog to `init` and `awakeFromNib` methods. `awakeFromNib` is called (as you said), the `init` is not. That's why I need to call it by myself.

Comment: go read about objects being read from nibs. you aren't "listening" to what I'm trying to tell you.  Calling init like you are is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've understood your sentence "If they are setup in the xib file then init is called" as referring to `init` call. That is incorrect. In case of nib object the method called is `initWithCoder`, not `init`. As for the problem, simple moving `init` logic to `initWithCoder` did not solve problem. There must be something else happening. Still investigating...